# How to transform a JSON data directly in a Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a lookup in a Azure Data Factory pipeline which is connected to a data flow. The lookup returns a JSON array in the form:

```
[
    {
        "COLUMN_NAME": "country_code"
    },
    {
        "COLUMN_NAME": "customer_role"
    },
    {
        "COLUMN_NAME": "valid_from"
    },
    {
        "COLUMN_NAME": "valid_to"
    }
]
```

The data flow accepts an array of strings as parameter. Therefore I need a way to transform the data from the lookup to an array of strings in the form:

```
[
    "country_code",
    "customer_role",
    "valid_from",
    "valid_to"
]
```

In my pipeline the output from the lookup is available as pipeline expression: `@activity('GetKeyColumns').output.value`.

For the data flow I can choose if I will use data flow expression or a pipeline expression to pass the parameter (array of strings). The data flow expression has a map function which is able to map the data structure. But I have no idea how I can use the output from the lookup in this function.

Is there a way how I can achieve this transformation in my pipeline?

Comment: Are your keys within JSON array of your look up activity the same?

Comment: Do you mean the object key? It is always COLUMN_NAME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a variable, type is array, then use For Each activity and append variable activity.

**Step:**

1.create a variable named string_array
[image]

2.create a For Each activity,expression:`@activity('GetKeyColumns').output.value`
[image]

3.create a Append variable activity inside For each avtivity,expression:`@item()['COLUMN_NAME']`
[image]

4.pass string_array to data flow by using pipeline expression:`@variables('string_array')`
[image]